# Get column type of a table using cql command

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to get column type of a table using cql command.
My table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid,
    name text);
```

Now I am trying to get type of `name` column. With the help of some select query I want to get `text` as output.

My use case is: I am trying to `drop name column only if type of name is text`

What script should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From CQL you can read this data from system tables. In Cassandra 3.x, this information is located in the `system_schema.columns` table that has following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE system_schema.columns (
    keyspace_name text,
    table_name text,
    column_name text,
    clustering_order text,
    column_name_bytes blob,
    kind text,
    position int,
    type text,
    PRIMARY KEY (keyspace_name, table_name, column_name)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (table_name ASC, column_name ASC);
```

so you can use query like this to retrieve the data:

```
select type from system_schema.columns where keyspace_name = 'your_ks' 
and table_name = 'users' and column_name = 'name';
```

In Cassandra 2.x, the structure of the system tables is different, so you may need to adapt your query.

If you're accessing cluster programmatically, then the driver hides differences between Cassandra versions, and you can use something like [Metadata class from Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/metadata/) to get information about table's structure and types of columns. But if you're doing schema changes programmatically, you **must** be careful and explicitly wait for [schema agreement](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/metadata/#schema-agreement), like in [following example](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/jdtest1/WhiteListPolicyExample.java#L37).

Answer (score -2):

```
select keyspace_name, table_name, column_name, type from system_schema.columns WHERE type='counter' AND keyspace_name='someName' LIMIT 100 ALLOW FILTERING ;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes